# new to Swift: How to update the detailTextLabel?.text

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and working on a small project.
I have two UITableViewController: TableViewController and DetailViewController.

Click on TableViewController cell will navigate to DetailViewController.
Click on DetailViewController cell will navigate back to TableViewController and update the detailTextLabel?.text with selected item.

The problem right now is I don't know how to update the detailTextLabel?.text.
I can pass the selected data from DetailViewController to TableViewController but not sure how to update the cell.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController,DataSelectedDelegate{
    var sessions=[Session]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.sessions = [Session(Game: "Game", Detail: "SuperTrack"),Session(Game: "Type",Detail : "Race")]


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func userSelectedInformatiom(info:NSString){
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text=info

    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.sessions.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var session:Session
        session=sessions[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = session.Game

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = sessions[indexPath.row].Detail
        return cell

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail"{
            let detailVC:DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
            detailVC.delegate=self
        }

    }


}
```

DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol DataSelectedDelegate{
    func userSelectedInformatiom(info:NSString)

}
class DetailViewController: UITableViewController {

        var types=[GameType]()
        var test:String!

        var delegate:DataSelectedDelegate? = nil

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



            self.types = [GameType(Type:"Race"),GameType(Type:"Shoot"),GameType(Type:"Kid"),GameType(Type:"Adult")]
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return types.count
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            //let identifier: String = "tableCell"
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cells", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            var type:GameType
            type=types[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = type.Type
            return cell
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            //println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

            //let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            //selectedCell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            if (delegate != nil){
                let selectedIndex:NSString=types[indexPath.row].Type
                delegate!.userSelectedInformatiom(selectedIndex)
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible solutions:

1. You can pass the selected cell to the detailViewController in `prepareForSegue` (the `sender` object is the tapped cell). Then you can pass that information back in your delegate call.
2. You can examine the indexPath of the selected row in the delegate function `userSelectedInformatiom` via `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()`. With that indexPath you get the cell via `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
3. You can store a reference to the selected cell before the segue is performed
4. ...